# Images don't show on browser Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, apache, laravel-5

I have some images saved and uploaded in the storage folder, I have created a link and the storage folder is accesible from the public folder. When I try to load the image using this code:

```
<img class="" style="width:100%" src="{{ asset('storage/Ad_Images/'.$adphoto->name ) }}" alt="Photo">
```

[This is what the Chrome dev tools show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO59k.jpg)

It should load but it looks like the image is there but something blocks it, if I click on the link in the image provided the browser shows the image

Comment: The `asset()` helper is used to create paths from the `public/` directory. You won't be able to access files from the storage path using this method.

Comment: Your question states that the `storage` folder is accessible from the `public` folder. By that, do you mean it is inside the `public` folder?

Comment: To address the above, if `storage/app/public` is linked to `public/storage` via `php artisan storage:link` (symlink generation), images uploaded in `storage` are accessible via `asset("storage/...")`. This is stated in the question, although somewhat vaguely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like blocked by AdBlock.

The solution is to remove from directory's name "Ad".

Comment: Can I change something to make it work even with Adblock on?

Comment: Remove from directory's name "Ad"

Answer (score -1):

You can't display images from storage directory. This is protected directory. If you want to display images on browser store images in public folder.